# Rust Multithreading only lock specific indices of vector

Tags: multithreading, rust

#### Situation

- I have an array of f32
- I have some threads that each will change a small part of the array
- I do not know which indices will be changed
- Every thread has to lock the array and then spend some time on an expensive calculation
- Afterwards, it will change the index and release the array
- Take a look at the commented minimal example below

#### The Problem

The first thread will lock the array and other threads can not edit it anymore. Thus wasting a lot of time. Other threads that need to edit different indices and would never touch the ones required by the first thread could have been executed at the same time.

#### Possible Solution

- I know that the array outlives all threads so unsafe Rust is a viable option
- I already posted a solution using the AtomicFloat external crate.
- You may come up with a stdlib-only solution.

Minimal example:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    // Store the mutex
    let container = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0.0; 10]));

    // This will keep track of the created threads
    let mut threads = vec![];

    // Create new Threads
    for _ in 0..10 {
        // Create a copy of the mutex reference
        let clone = Arc::clone(&container);

        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            // The function somehow calculates the index that has to be changed
            // In our case its simulated by picking a random index to emphasize that we do not know the index
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let index = rng.gen_range(0..10);

            // Unfortuantely we have to lock the array before the intense calculation !!!
            // If we could just lock the index of the array, other threads could change other indices in parallel
            // But now all of them need to wait for the lock
            let mut myarray = clone.lock().unwrap();

            // simulate intense calculation
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));

            // Now the index can be changed
            println!("Changing index {}", index);
            myarray[index] += 1.0;
        }));
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }

    // I know that myarray outlives the runtime of all threads.
    // Therefore someone may come up with an unsafe solution

    // Print the result
    println!("{:?}", container);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came up with using the atomic_float crate.

- [Introduction to scoped threads](https://betterprogramming.pub/scoped-threads-the-great-addition-of-rust-1-63-0-2a4c1d411c0a)
- [AtomicF32 docs](https://docs.rs/atomic_float/latest/atomic_float/struct.AtomicF32.html)

It works because the scoped thread ensures that all values live as long as the scope.
AtomicF32 protects the values from concurrent access

Note that this does not lock the index before the heavy work. When describing my problem I simplified it a bit. In reality, I had a loop that will often access the data thus almost constantly locking the array

```rust
use atomic_float::AtomicF32;
use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::thread::{self, sleep};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    // Create a new atomic float array
    // atomic floats ensure that the value is protected from concurrent access
    // Thus locking only the indecies
    // Notice the array is not mutable
    let myarray = [
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
        AtomicF32::new(0.0),
    ];

    // This is a scoped thread
    thread::scope(|s| {
        // The loop has to be inside the scope
        // All threads spawned within thread::scope must terminate before thread::scope can return
        // That's how it makes sure the scoped variables exist at least as long as the spawned threads
        for _ in 0..10 {
            //Create a new thread
            s.spawn(|| {
                let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
                let index = rng.gen_range(0..10);

                // Simulate heavy work
                sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));

                // Now the index can be changed
                println!("Changing index {}", index);
                // This is the atomic operation. The value is therefore protected from concurrent access
                myarray[index].fetch_add(1.0, Ordering::SeqCst)
            });
        }
    });
    println!("{:?}", myarray);
}
```

Comment: [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thread/fn.scope.html) are now available in std (starting from 1.63)

Comment: There is an important difference between the mutex-based example of the question and the atomic-based solution: the array is immutable during the (simulated) heavy work in one case, but not in the other. I don't know if this is relevant for your real problem, but it changes the question (you could lock the mutex at the very end of the computation in your question). But I agree, an atomic is much better if it suits the problem.

Comment: Thanks @prog-fh. Im going to update the answer with build in scoped threads later.

Comment: @prog-fh Yes you're right. I tried to simplify the problem a bit. Actually the heavy work is a loop that does a lot of changes to many indices which practically locks the entire array for a long period.